# PHP websocket - failing to build frame

Tags: php, websocket

I recently came across this website
https://phppot.com/php/simple-php-chat-using-websocket/ which gives some simple code for using websockets in PHP.

The function I'm struggling with looks like it might have been ported from C

```
    function seal($socketData) {
        $b1 = 0x80 | (0x1 & 0x0f);
        $length = strlen($socketData);

        if($length <= 125)
            $header = pack('CC', $b1, $length);
        elseif($length > 125 && $length < 65536)
            $header = pack('CCn', $b1, 126, $length);
        elseif($length >= 65536)
            $header = pack('CCNN', $b1, 127, $length);
        return $header.$socketData;
    }
```

But it doesn't seem to work. When I try to send more than 65536 bytes of data I get the following error

```
PHP Warning:  pack(): Type N: too few arguments in /var/www/html/class.chathandler.php on line 43
```

Line 43 is the following line:

```
            $header = pack('CCNN', $b1, 127, $length);
```

Can anyone help me fix this?

Answer (score 0):

"Simple PHP Chat using WebSocket" - LOL. Why would you use a binary protocol in a "simple" program?

```
 $header = pack('CCNN', $b1, 127, $length);
```

If you [read the fine manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php) you'll see the first argument to `pack()` is a description of the remaining arguments; one character per argument. In the code, you have 4 characters. But this is only followed by three arguments.

i.e. you have copied and pasted a bug from the article.

Without a lot of work, I can't tell you what the missing argument should be or if the format string is incorrect. If you need a chat application, I would suggest starting somewhere else.

Comment: I have already heavily adapted it. Everything else works fine - the handshake with the browser, queuing of multiple sockets etc. It just seems to be this one bug which I only just became aware of as I hadn't previously sent more than 65535 bytes. I've looked at [RFC6455](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455#section-5.2) but I'm not sure exactly what the seal function is trying to accomplish. Can anyone help me understand how it forms the header for the data packet?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I figured it out. I just needed to split the length in to big endian 32 bit integers

```
   function seal($socketData) {
      $b1 = 0x80 | (0x1 & 0x0f);
      $length = strlen($socketData);

      if($length <= 125)
         $header = pack('CC', $b1, $length);
      elseif($length > 125 && $length < 65536)
         $header = pack('CCn', $b1, 126, $length);
      elseif($length >= 65536) {
         $upper_32_bits = $length >> 32;
         $lower_32_bits = $length & 0xffffffff;
         $header = pack('CCNN', $b1, 127, $upper_32_bits, $lower_32_bits); }
      return $header.$socketData;
   }
```